# infinite loop in python interpreter

Tags: python-2.7, infinite-loop, python

I'm following along with python official tutorial.
I've created a fibonacci function `fib()` as shown on the tutorial,
The output from the function given argument `1` was(to my surprise),
infinite trails of `0`.

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     while a < n:
...         print a, 
...         a, b = b, a + b
... 
>>> fib(0)
>>> fib(1)
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (...repeats infinitely, had to break out with ^+Z ...)
```

I've tried to reproduce the issue, but couldn't succeed.

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     while a < n:
...         print a,
...         a, b = b, a + b
... 
>>> fib(0)
>>> fib(1)
0
>>> fib(1)
0
```

Is this a known issue or perhaps some temporary glitch in the interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this:

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     a,b = 0,1
...     while a < n:
...         print a,
...         a,b = b, a+b
... 
>>> fib(5)
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How did I do it?  The above code is really

```
def fib(n):
[tab]a,b = 0,1
[tab]while a < b:
[tab][4 spaces]print a,
[eight spaces]a,b = b, a+b
```

Mixing tabs and spaces confuses the interpreter about how it's supposed to parse the indentation.  As a result, the `a,b = b, a+b` line isn't actually inside the `while` loop, even though it looks like it.

Comment: for other beginners like me: running python with `-t`(or `-tt`) option will generate warnings(or errors) for inconsistent tab/space indentation.